# Division in C# results not exact value after decimal point

Tags: c#-4.0

Following division  showing incorrect result. It should be 15 digits after point according to the windows calculator. But in C# showing 14 digits after point.
[image]

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010

Comment: I also tried (Double)200/(Double)30 but showing same result.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed. It will be (Decimal)200/(Decimal)30 to be more Scale digits

Answer (score 0):

If numbers must add up correctly or balance, use decimal. This includes any financial storage or calculations, scores, or other numbers that people might do by hand.

If the exact value of numbers is not important, use double for speed. This includes graphics, physics or other physical sciences computations where there is already a "number of significant digits".

Please refer to below code for any further help.

```
C# Type .Net Framework (System) type    Signed? Bytes Occupied  Possible Values
    sbyte   System.Sbyte    Yes 1   -128 to 127
    short   System.Int16    Yes 2   -32768 to 32767
    int System.Int32    Yes 4   -2147483648 to 2147483647
    long    System.Int64    Yes 8   -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
    byte    System.Byte No  1   0 to 255
    ushort  System.Uint16   No  2   0 to 65535
    uint    System.UInt32   No  4   0 to 4294967295
    ulong   System.Uint64   No  8   0 to 18446744073709551615
    float   System.Single   Yes 4   Approximately ±1.5 x 10-45 to ±3.4 x 1038 with 7 significant figures
    double  System.Double   Yes 8   Approximately ±5.0 x 10-324 to ±1.7 x 10308 with 15 or 16 significant figures
    decimal System.Decimal  Yes 12  Approximately ±1.0 x 10-28 to ±7.9 x 1028 with 28 or 29 significant figures
    char    System.Char N/A 2   Any Unicode character (16 bit)
    bool    System.Boolean  N/A 1 / 2   true or false
```